# JaxB mapping multiple XMLTypes to single class

Tags: java, jaxb

How can I map two XMLTypes with different names but same content to a signle class. 
The Model generated from XSD looks like this. I would like to introduce a new Class Person that can have the XMLType Seller and Buyer.

```
@XmlType(name = "Seller")
public class Seller {
   private Sting name;
   private Adress adress;
   ....


@XmlType(name = "Buyer")
public class Buyer {
   private Sting name;
   private Adress adress;
   ....
```

This is how my xsd looks like when used:

```
<xs:complexType name="Business">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="vendor" type="ram:Seller" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="customer" type="ram:Buyer" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>  
</xs:complexType>
```

and the definition looks like this.

```
<xs:complexType name="Seller">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="udt:SType" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="address" type="udt:SType" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I guess one can workaround this problem by using an XML Adapter. But it would result in having 4 classes to maintain instead of the 2 now.

Is there a way where I end up with having only 1 Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this may help

```
public class Person {
private String name;
private Address address;
//getters & setters

}
```

And

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Business {
@XmlElement(name="buyer")
private Person buyer;
@XmlElement(name="seller")
private Person seller;
//getters & setters

}
```

Comment: what happens with the XMLTypes Seller and Buyers? will it work if I omit it?

Comment: apparently XMLTypes is not necessary as I thought at the beginning.

Comment: Is this possible to be specified via bindings.xml file? Not through modifying java code?